# How/where to store temp files and logs for a cloud app?

Tags: python, mysql, redis, cloud, storage

I am working on a Python/MySQL cloud app with a fairly complex architecture. Operating this system (currently) generates temporary files (plain text, YAML) and log files and I had intended to store them on the filesystem.

However, our prospective cloud operator only provides a temporary, non-persistent filesystem to apps. This means that the initial approach with storing the temporary and log files won't work.

There must be a standard approach to solving this problem which I am not aware of. I don't want to use object storage like S3 because it would extend the current stack and add complexity. But I have the possibility to install an additional, dedicated app (if there is anything made for this purpose) on a different server with the same provider. The only limitation is that it would have to be in PHP, Python, MySQL.

The generic question: *What is the standard approach to storing files when no persistent filesystem is available?*

And for my specific case: *Is there any solution using Python and/or MySQL which is simple and quick to implement? Is this a usecase for Redis?*

Comment: This is a bit too vague for an answer. Can you specify what cloud solution you want to use? Do you want to store them in the same cloud or on another server? Can you use anything else aside from Python/MySQL? Can you install anything else?

Comment: Added some more info. Thought the question was generic... standard approach to storing files when no persistent filesystem is available...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are asking two questions, let me also answer them one by one:

> The generic question: What is the standard approach to storing files when no persistent filesystem is available?

If the contents of a file are not suitable for regular database storage, but you really want to store the file itself (like images, binaries, etc) persistently, Amazon S3 and similar services are usually your way to go. There are also free alternatives available like [Riak](http://basho.com/), [Aerospike](http://www.aerospike.com/) or the more heavy [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/).

While all of these services are free (or have free versions available), they would require setup and ongoing maintenance. Also you are very unlikely to achieve the same levels of availability and scalability as hosted cloud services like S3 have. If you account for this, the savings by not using a cloud service like S3 are questionable at least. But as always, YMMV.

> And for my specific case: Is there any solution using Python and/or MySQL which is simple and quick to implement? Is this a usecase for Redis?

Your question is a little bit contradictory. You mention your application generates *temporary* files, yet you don't want to lose them?

If your files are temporary, a solution like [Redis](http://redis.io/) or [memcached](https://memcached.org/) would be perfectly suitable for the job, as long as you have the understanding that both are *caches* and data will be lost on restart, or (if enabling Redis snapshots) at least don't guarantee that writes are persisted to disk.

If you do not want to extend your stack, and Redis does not give you the levels of guarantees you are looking for, MySQL supports the storage of [blobs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html), which can be used for storing files (binary data) in MySQL. This generally does not scale very well, but again, deciding whether this is acceptable for you highly depends on your situation. (See also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/150787) excellent answer regarding the pro's and con's of storing files in MySQL.)

Answer (score 1):

Redis is a bad choice for this problem.
It keeps all data in memory, so it's expensive and not practical for long term keeping of log files.

MySql is OK, however MongoDB is a more flaxible and fast solution.
Actually it's one of it's main use cases: https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-log-data/

Answer (score -1):

Store your logs in MySQL. Just make a table like this:

```
x***time*****source*****action
----------------------------
****unixtime*somemodule*error/event
```

Your temporary storage should be enough for temporary files :)

Comment: Okay for the logs, but where do I put the temporary plain text files? They have to persist over some time until I delete them manually.

Comment: You didn't provide any other solution except MySQL. So probably MySQL. There is no other option...

Comment: Sure, but certainly not in the table structure you showed. I guess there has to be some optimization. I also said Python, so maybe Redis would be another option?

Comment: The table structure I showed was for logs. I don't know what's the structure of your text files.

Comment: The text files have different structures, including YAML, so I guess they should be stored in a text field or a blob. But is that efficient if I need to write to those files frequently ???

Comment: In your files, are there data that can be structurized to be saveable to a database? If you need to write to these files frequently, are you just appending or modifying the file from scratch, doing minor edits in the middle?

Comment: All of them: I am appending, doing minor edits and writing from scratch.

Comment: I recommend using text fields. Editing them won't require to rewrite the whole table, because the data are stored outside the table and in the table is only an anchor to these data. (BLOB does the same)

Comment: The same: the data are stored in a file outside the table. (+some DB overhead)